# linq with nested and complex where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this query that works fine.

```
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SDBEN> benefici = context.Benefici.Include("Titolare").Include("Titolare.ComuneDomicilio")
        .Where(b => !b.Titolare.DATA_DECESSO.HasValue &&
              !b.DATA_FINE.HasValue &&                                 
        .OrderBy(b => b.Titolare.COGNOME)
        .ThenBy(b => b.Titolare.NOME)
        .ThenBy(b => b.Titolare.DATA_NASCITA)
        .ThenBy(b => b.CODICE) 
        .ToList();
```

Each "Titolare" has several "Fascia" even duplicated.
I would like that "Titolare" who have the last "FASCIA" with code 50 with a "MOTIVO_FINE" equal to 00 or 01 were not considered.

Something like this

```
System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SDBEN> benefici = context.Benefici.Include("Titolare").Include("Titolare.ComuneDomicilio")
        .Where(b => !b.Titolare.DATA_DECESSO.HasValue &&
              (!b.DATA_FINE.HasValue || 
                (b.FASCIA == 50 && 
                 context.Benefici.Where(a => a.CODICE == b.Titolare.CODICE).OrderByDescending(a => a.DATA_FINE).FirstOrDefault().DATA_FINE == b.DATA_FINE &&
                                  b.MOTIVO_FINE != "00" &&
                                  b.MOTIVO_FINE != "01")
              ) &&                                 
        .OrderBy(b => b.Titolare.COGNOME)
        .ThenBy(b => b.Titolare.NOME)
        .ThenBy(b => b.Titolare.DATA_NASCITA)
        .ThenBy(b => b.CODICE) 
        .ToList();
```

The above code does not work.
Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

something like that

```
INPUT

CODICE  COGNOME NOME        DATA_DECESSO    FASCIA  DATA_FINE       MOTIVO_FINE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1000    PIPPO   PLUTO       NULL            30      NULL            NULL
1001    PIPPO   PAPERINO    NULL            30      01-01-2000      04
1001    PIPPO   PAPERINO    NULL            30      NULL            NULL
1001    PIPPO   PAPERINO    NULL            50      01-01-2020      00
1001    PIPPO   PAPERINO    NULL            50      01-01-2021      00
1002    TIZIO   CAIO        NULL            50      01-01-2020      02
1002    TIZIO   CAIO        NULL            50      01-01-2021      01
1003    TOPO    TOPOLINO    NULL            30      NULL            NULL
1003    TOPO    TOPOLINO    NULL            50      01-01-2020      01
1003    TOPO    TOPOLINO    NULL            50      01-01-2021      02
1004    PIPPO2  PLUTO2      NULL            30      01-01-2021      05


OUTPUT

CODICE  COGNOME NOME        DATA_DECESSO    FASCIA  DATA_FINE       MOTIVO_FINE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1000    PIPPO   PLUTO       NULL            30      NULL            NULL
1001    PIPPO   PAPERINO    NULL            30      NULL            NULL
1003    TOPO    TOPOLINO    NULL            30      NULL            NULL
1003    TOPO    TOPOLINO    NULL            50      01-01-2021      02
```

Comment: Funny, first one doesn't look like it should work at all..

Comment: Do you want to use any rather than firstOrDefault in context.Benefici?

Comment: @Den: with any() I have a compilation error

Comment: It's not easy for me to understand the desired outcome. Can you share a input set and expected output?